# Calendar fills from the right side

Tags: javascript, loops, calendar, html-table

I'm making a calendar and I'm at the point now where I'm supposed to let every month start on the right day (otherwise they'd all start on Sunday). I've made an array containing the amount of empty data cells I need to have every month before the days start counting up. I managed to make it fill the calendar with the right amount of empty data cells, however, the empty data cells start filling up in the first row from the right side while it should logically start at the left side.

I've included a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGgtA.jpg) to show what it looks like on my PC:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGgtA.jpg]

code:

```
var months = new Array();
months[0] = "januari";
months[1] = "februari";
months[2] = "maart";
months[3] = "april";
months[4] = "mei";
months[5] = "juni";
months[6] = "juli";
months[7] = "augustus";
months[8] = "september";
months[9] = "oktober";
months[10] = "november";
months[11] = "december";

var maxDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var spaces = [2, 5, 5, 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 0];
var weekDays = ["zo", "ma", "di", "wo", "do", "vr", "za"];
var kalender = 0;
var days = 1;
var weekDaysNumber = 0;
var empty = 1;



while(kalender < months.length){
    document.write("<div id='table'><table><tr class='jaarrij'>");
    document.write("<th colspan='7'>" + months[kalender] + "</th></tr>");
    document.write("<tr class='weekrij'>");

    while(weekDaysNumber <= 6){
        document.write("<td>" + weekDays[weekDaysNumber] + "</td>");
        weekDaysNumber++
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
    document.write("<tr class='rij'>");

    var rows = 1;

    while(days < maxDays[kalender]){

        if(spaces[kalender] >= 1) {
            document.write("<td class='dag'>" + " " + "</td");

            rows++;
            spaces[kalender]--;

        }

        else if(spaces[kalender] < 1){
            document.write("<td class='dag'>" + days + "</td>");



            rows++;
            days++;
        }





        if(rows == 7 && days !== maxDays[kalender]){
        document.write("</tr>");
        document.write("<tr class='rij'>");
        rows = 0;
        }

    }

    if(days == maxDays[kalender]){
            document.write("</tr></table></div>");
            kalender++;
            weekDaysNumber=0;
            days= 1;

        }
}
```

Comment: You've hardcoded the numbers of days in a month and the number of spaces needed so unless you don't want this to work for any date you're going to be stuck.  I use getDay() for a given Date which returns 1-7 depending on the day of the week. You can use that to add spaces.  The "if(spaces[kalender] < 1)" is redundant .. as for the cell order.. can't immediately see why. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I'm new to fiddle but I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mellow/pWPfn/) should work. EDIT: It only works for me when I press run otherwise it loads forever. The css also doesn't initialize for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how I missed this but you've not closed the  tag of the line that adds the blank days..

You can simply use

```
<td class='dag'></td>
```

too rather than +" "+